# Из txt в sql файл

Tags: php

```
<?php
ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');
define("ROOT",realpath(__DIR__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
$file = ROOT.'data.txt';
if(is_file($file)){
    $csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file($file));
    $arr = '';
    if(is_array($csv)){
        foreach($csv as $line){
            $arr[] = array('guid'=>$line[0],'icon'=>$line[1]);
        }
    }
    $head = 'INSERT INTO `tab_icon` (`id`, `icon`) VALUES';
    foreach($arr as $ln){
        $head .= "('{$ln['guid']}','{$ln['icon']}'), \n";
    }
    $head = substr($head, 0, -3).';';
    file_put_contents(ROOT.'tab_icon.sql',$head);
}?>
```

Мой код, которым я читаю по-строчно файл txt
Содержимое файла:

1 weapon_small_sword_i00
2 weapon_long_sword_i00
3 weapon_broad_sword_i00
4 weapon_club_i00
5 weapon_mace_i00

и тд.

Подскажите, каким образом я могу извлечь мои данные таким образом -   (`id`, `icon`). В моем случае сохраняется все построчно в 1 колонку, а вторая пустая

Comment: в смысле построчно?

Comment: В данном примере sql файл создается так:     ('2 weapon_long_sword_i00 ',''),    а мне нужно вот так  ('2','weapon_long_sword_i00'),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так можно получить данные:

```
<?php
ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');
define("ROOT",realpath(__DIR__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
$file = ROOT.'data.txt';
if(is_file($file)){
    $data = file_get_contents($file);
    $rows = explode(PHP_EOL, $data);
    $head = 'INSERT INTO `tab_icon` (`id`, `icon`) VALUES';
    foreach ($rows as $k => $row){
        $cell = explode(' ', $row);
        $head .= "('{$cell[0]}','{$cell[1]}')";
        if ($k < count($rows)) {
             $head .= ", \n";
        }
    }
    file_put_contents(ROOT.'tab_icon.sql',$head);
}
?>
```

Comment: Не совсем поняла как это.. Вы не могли бы показать на примере моего кода?

Comment: Поправил ответ. Я с php много лет не работал, не знаю что в нем есть парсер csv и не знаю причин его неправильной работы. Поэтому использую обычный парсер строк и пробелов. Так-же могу где-то ошибиться в синтаксисе, к примеру не знаю что за фигурные скобки `{}`

Comment: Ваш код к сожалению не дал результатов(   ('2 weapon_long_sword_i00',''),

Comment: Значит не сработал explode строки по пробелу, может там какой-то другой разделительный символ вроде табуляции?

Comment: Удалила лишние строки, табы и тд, вроде бы теперь пробел, но результата нет по прежнему(

Comment: Мистика, ну пробуйте по отдельности выводить баз сохранения в sql, отдельно cell[0] cell[1], и может без фигурных скобок?

Comment: Эм..мы не поняли друг друга.. в моем коде я сохраняю вывод в sql файл. Ваш код этого не делает, он вообще не сохраняет ничего (

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45152/discussion-between-artem-gorlachev-and-).